# How to use JPMML-Android to implement a PMML machine learning model?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, pmml

I've created a PMML Random Forest model using scikit-learn in Python, and my goal is to implement that model in an Android app to do live predictions. From a previous question, the best way to go about this seemed to be using JPMML-Android (https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android). However, there's no tutorials, and given how new I am to this, I'm not sure at all what's going on in that 'Usage' section. Any help would be greatly appreciated on how I can use this to implement my model!

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android/blob/master/pmml-android-example/src/main/java/org/jpmml/android/MainActivity.java

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks, but I've already looked at that. It doesn't really help a whole lot, because I'm not sure how to use my PMML model with that, what I need to set up to get that code itself to work, and I'm not sure based off of the code how to do live predictions (feeding in my own inputs).

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

1. put your .pmml file in the directory:

> jpmml-android-master\pmml-android-example\src\main\pmml\

2. install the mvn plugin: e.g. in windows cmd:

> mvn clean install

3. find your .ser file in the directory:

> jpmml-android-master\pmml-android-example\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\

The 2nd step compile the code and convert the .pmml file to .ser file.

Then you can follow the example code in

> jpmml-android-master\pmml-android

to build the android project in Android Studio to use the .ser model.